# What differences are there between processors of different ranges but with similar/identical specs?

Tags: cpu

Could someone please explain what the difference is between an i3 processor and an i7 processor that both have the same clock speed and similar other characteristics?

What benefits are there in choosing an i7 processor over an i3 if both of them have the **similar specs**?

I heard that these ranges do not exist just for marketing reasons, there are some technical differences too between ranges of processors, and this does not only apply to Intel. What I wanted to know was what exactly these ***differences in manufacturing, design***, etc, ... are and what their **real impacts** are **on** the **performance** of these processors.

I also heard that **process variability at manufacturing** was an important issue and that i7s were subject to tougher controls that i3s for example so there would be less performance variability between i7s than i3s for example. Is this true, and if so how is this done ?

Comment: As per the excellent comments of my post (which I deleted) from mnmnc and hennes, please see http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processor-comparison/compare-intel-processors.html#cont3 for a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

First I will say if you want this answer to determine which processors you should buy, look at *benchmarks* instead. They will give you a much more reliable comparison between processors.

I'm also assuming you are only concerned with the differences between Intel and AMD processors. There are other brands that design processors for non-desktop computers (gaming consoles, mobile phones, etc), and outlining the differences between all of these would probably make any sane person crack.

Having said that, here's some differences:

**Differences you will see on the box:**

- Amount of cores (i3 usually has 2 cores, i7 will usually have 4)
- Clock Speed
- Overclocking ability
- Cache size (L1, L2, and L3 cache sizes)
- Fabrication size (refers to the separation between memory cells. IE `22nm`)
- Power dissipation (generally correlated to the fabrication size)
- Quality of on-board graphics (though, not all processors even have this)
- Support for hyper-threading

**Differences you won't see on the box:**

- Bus sizes
- [Dhrystone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone) instructions per second
- FLOPS (floating point instructions per second)

**Differences uncommonly found:**

- Support for branch prediction (most Intel processors have this, I think)
- Maximum memory (3rd generation Intel Processors maxed out at `32GB`, I believe the 4th goes up to `64GB`).

There are many other differences I could mention, but these are most relevant to end-users. If you are a programmer, for example, the different abilities of the processor's instruction set may make a *big* difference to you. If you are a system administration, you're probably more focused on server processors (commonly Xeon processors).

**Manufacturing:**

i7s are not *subject to higher controls* in the way that you think they are. This is how the different `i3`s `i5`s and `i7`s generally come about:

- A Single CPU is designed, fabricated, etc.
- Batches of the CPU are run through intense performance tests (*How many cores are correctly running? What's the max clock frequency? How much power does it dissipate? etc*)
- Features of each processor are disabled or limited based on the test results
- The processors are then divided and labeled accordingly

This process is called [binning](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/249242-28-binning) and is common many different manufactures and products of the solid state type. Therefore, i3s aren't *designed* differently than i7s. In fact, it's the same design, just different fabrication results (the fabrication process isn't perfect).

As DavidSchwartz pointed out - if a company needs more of a certain lesser processor (ie more `i3`s of a line of processors), they will physically disable some features (even if they pasted the test results) of a better batch to make it equivalent to the lesser module.

**Making a rough comparison (Intel):**

- Check the cache sizes (L1, L2, and L3)
- Can it overclock? How much?
- How many cores?
- How much power does it consume?
- How much ram does it support (also depends on the motherboard)
- Does it have on-board graphics?
- What generation processor is this? (right now, Intel has four. A new one every ~ year).
- Does it support hyper-threading?

Comment: What generation they are matters too. Least between the 1st and 2nd generation cores, a 2nd gen core i3 was roughly comparable to a 1st generation core i5. You also get some additional things like new features (quicksync on the newer core models come to mind) and better onboard graphics. There's also different processes between them with newer processes being more power efficient

Comment: Also, part of binning is often disabling cores, caches, parts of caches, limiting the multiplier, and so on. Each die has a set of links that can be cut by laser. If Intel needs more of a particular CPU, they may take parts that qualify perfectly for more cores, more cache, or hyper-threading and disable those features by laser to get the CPU they need to sell.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts thanks, that's informative. I've added that to my answer